# what is the following cmake snippet do?

Tags: cmake

```
set(TestProject_additional_libs
        optimized  foobar.lib   
        debug   foobard.lib    
}
```

especially what is optimized/debug mean here? Is this the standard way to add libs using cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a "misuse" to me. Those all are just assigned to a variable `TestProject_additional_libs`. The magic happens probably later when it is expanded in something like [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries). I did not know one can do something like that. But indeed it is not clear what actually is going on when it is written this way.

Citing the manual from aforementioned link:

> A "debug", "optimized", or "general" keyword indicates that the
>   library immediately following it is to be used only for the
>   corresponding build configuration.

Comment: What mlt said; most likely there are two versions of the library built and when target_link_libraries is called it'll use the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to figure out which one to link against.

Comment: @mlt It's not a misuse, it's how `target_link_libraries` is designed to work.

Comment: @Doug `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only supported for make based generators, so the documentation @mlt quotes regarding "build configuration" is technically more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This sets the value of variable `TestProject_additional_libs` to a semi-colon-separated list containing `optimized;foobar.lib;debug;foobard.lib`.

Normally, `${TestProject_additional_libs}` would then be used in a [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) command to indicate that `foobar.lib` should be used for optimised builds (like Release) and `foobard.lib` should be used in debug builds:

```
target_link_libraries(<target> <files> ${TestProject_additional_libs})
```

To avoid creating a temporary variable, you could also use a similar syntax in the `target_link_libraries` call itself:

```
target_link_libraries(<target> <files> optimized foobar.lib debug foobard.lib)
```